# People will feel boring/bored ... which is appropriate?

Tags: grammaticality

> people will feel bor**ing** if advertisements give information only.
>
> people will feel bor**ed** if advertisements give information only.

Please tell me if I should choose **bored** or **boring**.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! I've edited your question title to make it more useful. If you feel I have misunderstood you, please feel free to [edit] it yourself. In future, please make sure your title is descriptive and that it accurately represents your question.

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary to discover how these words are used, or what the underlying verb means? If/when you have, report what you have found and what still puzzles you.

Answer (score 1):

**People will feel boring if advertisements give information only.** This is not correct.

"Boring" is an adjective and should therefore only be used to describe a noun. If you say "people feel boring" then you are literally saying that these people do not feel good about themselves; they feel that they do not offer enough entertainment to others, and they are comparing themselves to those around them, believing that they are not as fun as other people.

**People will feel bored if advertisements give information only.** This is the correct sentence.

By saying "people will feel bored" you are saying that there is boredom, and these people feel it.

Answer (score 0):

**"people will feel boring"** = people will be aware that they do not provide enough entertainment, to others or to themselves

**"people will be bored"** = people will not receive enough entertainment from their environment (other people, activities, technology...)

In the case of advertisements, they are boring if they are not interesting / exciting, and people will be bored and will want to watch something else.

Answer (score -1):

Boring describes an activity, not a person. On the other hand, bored describes an emotion. That is why it's better to say "People will feel bored..."

Comment: People can be described as boring in the same way anything else can: if they tend to bore others.